# Why does Google's Sheet not contain any Data, while in reality it does have data?

Tags: c#, wpf, request, google-sheets-api

**I'm trying to get the Data from an already polled Sheet, in a Google Spreadsheet**

**>> using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 NuGet**

```
    public void GoFunction(string spreadsheetId, string sheetname)
    {
        var spreadsheet = GoogleService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId).Execute();
        var sheet = spreadsheet.Sheets.Where(x => x.Properties.Title.Equals(sheetname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var data = sheet.Data;
    }
```

but for some reason, I only have properties about the sheet itself, the Data object is null, while there is actually data in that sheet.
What am i doing wrong here ? The goal is to make a GetCellColor() and SetCellColor() once i get the Cells from the Sheets' Data (for now)

How to get to the GridData this way, as there is no option to define a Grid in requesting it as such, i need to get to the userEnteredFormat the Cells contain. (same for the TextFormats, eg FontBold and ForeColor etc)

Comment: I notice the same for Google Drive (Google.Apis.Drive.v3), GoogleDriveService.Files.List() only has Name and FileID, everything else is null. How to define what Google should include in the request by default ?

Comment: Are using a service account?

Comment: No, i'm not, this is just with a token the user gives access to

Comment: Like this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: I seem to have found a missing link via a Google Drive example i bumped into !
The Requests have a property called "Fields", which requires a string in a specific format in order to identify what field values should be included in the return.

From the Drive example i found it was "files(id, name)", and only those 2 values weren't null.
This is available on every Request made with the Google.Apis libraries.
Unfortunately, I am finding a Request to fetch the Spreadsheets, as well as the Values, but not one for the Worksheets. Nor the correct syntax of the fields definition string required.

Comment: The example from Google Drive i was talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343287/selecting-specific-fields-with-google-drive-api-v2

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer: from https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#SpreadsheetsService

"Get: Returns the spreadsheet at the given ID. The caller must specify the spreadsheet ID. **By default, data within grids is not returned. You can include grid data in one of 2 ways:** * Specify a field mask (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/field-masks) listing your desired fields using the `fields` URL parameter in HTTP * Set the includeGridData URL parameter to true. If a field mask is set, the `includeGridData` parameter is ignored For large spreadsheets, as a best practice, retrieve only the specific spreadsheet fields that you want. To retrieve only subsets of spreadsheet data, use the ranges URL parameter. Ranges are specified using A1 notation (/sheets/api/guides/concepts#cell). You can define a single cell (for example, `A1`) or multiple cells (for example, `A1:D5`). You can also get cells from other sheets within the same spreadsheet (for example, `Sheet2!A1:C4`) or retrieve multiple ranges at once (for example, `?ranges=A1:D5&ranges=Sheet2!A1:C4`). Limiting the range returns only the portions of the spreadsheet that intersect the requested ranges."

Your service call did not include fields which are necessary.